# How do I get Python to not add excessive spacing when I convert to PDF

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, spacing

I'm trying to get my pdf to look more nice and neet like the first picture and less like the second

[This is how I'm trying to get it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d16Ox.png)

[This is how it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWrRW.png)

```
myFoodsDF = pd.read_sql(getQuery(), conn)
print(myFoodsDF.info())
print(myFoodsDF)

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
spacing = 1
col_width1 = pdf.w / 4.5
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=15)
row_height = pdf.font_size
pdf.cell(0, row_height*spacing, txt='Foods and Recipies', border=0, align='C', ln=1)

groupedDF = myFoodsDF.groupby(['Food'])['Recipe'].agg(', '.join)
print(groupedDF[0])
for row in groupedDF.iteritems() :
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
    pdf.multi_cell(col_width1, row_height*spacing, txt=row[0].strip(), border=1, align='L')
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=10)
    pdf.multi_cell(0, row_height*spacing, txt=row[1].strip(), border=1, align='L')
    pdf.ln(row_height*spacing)
pdf.output("Foods.pdf")
```

Comment: where are these defined or what are they please ?  `getQuery()`, `conn`, `FPDF()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.